# Passing Checkbox input from one fragment to another

Tags: android

I have a list of checkboxes in a fragment (lets call it FragmentA) and I have an activity with 2 fragments (FragmentB and C) in it. If a checkbox is selected, I want to show a message in Fragment C that the particular checkbox has been selected. I need help as I don't know how to pass the (isChecked) from FragmentA to Fragment C.

FragmentA.java

```
 CB16.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            int finalScore = Values.getInstance().updateScore(CB16.getId());
            if (CB16.isChecked()) {
                score = score + finalScore;
            } else if (!CB16.isChecked()) {
                score = score - finalScore;
                tv.setText(" " + score);
            }
        }
    });

    CB17.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            int finalScore = Values.getInstance().updateScore(CB17.getId());
            if (CB17.isChecked()) {
                score = score + finalScore;
            } else if (!CB17.isChecked()) {
                score = score - finalScore;
                tv.setText(" " + score);
            }
        }
    });


    CB18.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            int finalScore = Values.getInstance().updateScore(CB18.getId());
            if (CB18.isChecked()) {
                score = score + finalScore;
            } else if (!CB18.isChecked()) {
                score = score - finalScore;
                tv.setText(" " + score);
            }
        }
    });


    CB19.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            int finalScore = Values.getInstance().updateScore(CB19.getId());
            if (CB19.isChecked()) {
                score = score + finalScore;
            } else if (!CB19.isChecked()) {
                score = score - finalScore;
                tv.setText(" " + score);
            }
        }
    });


    CB20.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            int finalScore = Values.getInstance().updateScore(CB20.getId());
            if (CB20.isChecked()) {
                score = score + finalScore;
            } else if (!CB20.isChecked()) {
                score = score - finalScore;
                tv.setText(" " + score);
            }
        }
    });

    CB21.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            int finalScore = Values.getInstance().updateScore(CB21.getId());
            if (CB21.isChecked()) {
                score = score + finalScore;
            } else if (!CB21.isChecked()) {
                score = score - finalScore;
                tv.setText(" " + score);
            }
        }
    });


    CB22.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            int finalScore = Values.getInstance().updateScore(CB22.getId());
            if (CB22.isChecked()) {
                score = score + finalScore;
            } else if (!CB22.isChecked()) {
                score = score - finalScore;
                tv.setText(" " + score);
            }
        }
    });





    btnFragMale6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            ((MainActivityMale)getActivity()).setViewPager(6);            }
    });






    return view;

}
```

The score does not influence FragmentC.

The Activity containing Fragment B and C

```
 FragmentB fragmentb = new FragmentB();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.constraintLayout1,fragmentB,fragmentB.getTag())
            .commit();

    FragmentC fragmentc = new FragmentC();
    FragmentManager fragmentManagerrslt = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManagerC.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.constraintLayout2,fragmentC,fragmentC.getTag())
            .commit();
```

FragmentC Activity

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_c, container, false);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: started");


    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways you could go about sharing information between activities and fragments. One is by manually passing them through on every switch as arguments. The second (which sounds most similar to what you might want) is storing the checkbox data in shared preferences.

### Passing them through as arguments

Since you mentioned your fragments are in a different activity, you would first have to pass your arguments (the checkbox values) to the next activity which could then pass them on to fragments.

**Example of passing arguments to new activity**

Put a boolean `checkboxValue` along with a unique id for that checkbox into the new `Intent`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putBoolean("key", checkboxValue); //Your id
intent.putExtras(b); //Put your id to your next Intent
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Then grab the id in your new `Activity`:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
boolean checkboxValue = false; // or other values
if(b != null)
    value = b.getBoolean("key", false);
```

**Example of passing arguments to fragments**

When you create your fragment, just add arguments to it as shown below:

```
Fragment f = new FragmentC();
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putBoolean("uniqueId", checkboxValue);
f.setArguments(b);
```

And then use that fragment in your `FragmentTransaction`

Getting it out of the fragment later is done as shown below in the `onCreate` or `onCreateView` method:

```
Bundle args = getArguments();
int checkboxValue = args.getBoolean("uniqueId", false);
```

### Using SharedPreferences

Shared Preferences is a global store of data for your app. You can put in and get out data from it in any part of your app. An example of putting data is shown below

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit()
edit.putBoolean("checkbox1", checkboxValue)
edit.apply()
```

And when you want to get that data out from some other part of your app, you would do it as so:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()
boolean checkboxValue = prefs.get("checkbox1", false)
```

This is a great way to store global settings in your app! Learn more [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences)

Comment: great answer, there is another way too through which we pass data from activity to fragment is by using interfaces.

Comment: Thank you so much. Great answer with great explanations!