# Passing checkbox input from one fragment to another fragment in the same activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have fragment A with checkboxes and fragment B with EditText to write.

I want to disable the Edittext of fragment B when Fragment A checkbox is checked.

Y tried with Shared Preferences but it's does not disable nothing.

In Fragment A:

```
CheckBox.setChecked(client.getUCheckbox);

CheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean b) {
            if (b){       
             
                SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sharedPref.edit();
                edit.putBoolean("CheckBox", true);
                edit.apply();
            }
```

In fragment B:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    sharedPref.getBoolean("Checkbox",false);
```

}

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(
        @NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_determinaciones_parte_aguas, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, root);

    rellenarVista();

    return root;
}

 private void rellenarVista() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    sharedPref.getBoolean("CheckBox",false);

    if (CheckBox){
        disableEditText();
    }
```

disableEditText is a method that set enable as false to all the editText.

The solution I tried is from this post.

[Passing Checkbox input from one fragment to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51806131/passing-checkbox-input-from-one-fragment-to-another)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use a shared ViewModel scoped the lifecycle of the activity to share data between fragments. See docs https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: your `disableEditText();` method is only called once in fragment B's `onCreateView()`, when the fragment is created. You should pass a reference to fragment B to fragment A (or the parent activity) and update the check box directly in fragment A's `onCheckedChanged()`

The preferences you are using are private to the requesting activity.

You need to store your boolean in preferences accessible from both activities. Instead of

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

you can use:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
```

Note: your `onCheckedChanged()` implementation does not update the flag if the checkbox is unchecked. Here is a fix:

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean b) {

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sharedPref.edit();
    edit.putBoolean("CheckBox", b);
    edit.apply();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer but it's not working, I'm able to asign a true value and the other fragment disable the EditText but i cannot perform this task with the checkbox input in execution time.

Comment: That's because your disableEditText(); method is only called once in  fragment B's onCreateView(), when the fragment is created. You should pass a reference to fragment B to fragment A (or the parent activity) and update the check box directly in fragment A's onCheckedChanged()